# How to get GPS location and send in SMS android

Tags: android, gps, sms

I can not get the GPS to work. I am saving it in a SharedPreference called gps and it will print in a Toast as "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat +  " , " + lon 
this is so when it is sent in a SMS they receiver can just push the link and it opens the map. But when the toast comes up it is blank. Below is my code.

```
private void showLocation() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {}

        public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, loc_listener);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    double lat, lon;
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        lat = -1.0;
        lon = -1.0;
    }

          prefs.setPreferenceString(getApplicationContext(),"gps" ,"http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat +  " , " + lon);



}
```

Comment: post code where u r setting lat long into shared preferences and toast.

Comment: Walk through the debugger and see what values the lat/long gives you. It may be that you don't have a last known location, or that you're indoors where the GPS doesn't work. Also, you should put the relevant lat/long code into onLocationChanged to detect location changes and update the lat/long accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find your location try to use GPSTracker. [link](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apis/blob/master/WhereAmI/src/com/errorpoint/whereami/GPSTracker.java)

And use this code.

```
        gps = new GPSTracker(LauncherActivity.this);
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
```

And one more things, check your device, is it support GPS? And is it (GPS) enable? If your device's GPS is not enable, you will get null....

For more help... check my github [repo](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apis/tree/master/WhereAmI)

Answer (score 0):

[I am trying to make such app](https://github.com/lcharles123/SMSTracker), here are the code for toast that works well:

```
  Handler handler3 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler3.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Toast.makeText(context,"mensagem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```